# In Cassandra, how to get the execution time of each stage(computation, read, write) of a single compaction thread?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The computation operation consists of decoding, merging and encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if those metrics are collected in that detail. But you can extrapolate that information if you parse the logs.

You'll need to write an app/script which would calculate the individual execution time based on the following values you can infer from the compaction threads in the logs:

- when a compaction thread started
- when a compaction thread completed
- the compaction throughput for a given thread

I don't believe there's an out-of-the-box solution for it though I'm happy to be corrected.

The thing is I don't know how useful the information would be in terms of day-to-day operation so I suspect there's a lot more behind your question. If you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve, I'd be happy to update my answer. Cheers!